# Simplepie can't write specific feed's cache file

Tags: php, caching, rss, simplepie

I have this very odd problem where only one of my (6) feeds won't display anything on the page.

So, I checked the server and apparently just this one feed's cache file won't get written. There are also no errors displayed on the page to indicate anything.

The posts I've been reading, talk only about (a) having the cache location set wrong or (b) setting the wrong permissions. I've checked both:

a) Quite impossible since it's only one feed that doesn't get cached, the other ones work just fine
b) Again, impossible. Permissions are set correctly.

**Code:**

```
require_once('components/autoloader.php');

// Set feed
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($rsslink);

// Set cache
$feed->enable_cache(true);
$feed->set_cache_location($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/hoig/cache');
// The line below works as well
// $feed->set_cache_location('cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration(1800);

// Run
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
```

The `$rsslink` that isn't working: http://ontwikkelcentrum.nl/rss.php

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` links to /var/www/html and my website is in a folder named 'hoig'. The cache folder is in there of course.

I'm at loss, but I need to get this fixed asap.
**Any ideas are greatly appreciated.**

EDIT: Just to say, it is working locally. Just not on a particular server.

Comment: Maybe ontwikkelcentrum.nl is blocking your IP, can you enable error reporting and see if any errors show up, or make separate php script `var_dump(file_get_contents(feedurl));`

Comment: I can't enable reporting, not my server so I can't tamper with it. You do mean like `var_dump(file_get_contents('http://ontwikkelcentrum.nl/rss.php'));`? The connection seemed to time out

Comment: Than they are blocking your server IP. Try using a proxy as thats same command works for me.

Comment: I managed to fix it. The problem was DNS resolving. Both the feed and the website are on the same server. And they couldn't communicate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was DNS resolving.

Both the feed and the website are on the same server. And they couldn't communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Tip for others searching this (your code was fine) - ensure that any `$feed->set_cache_location('/path/to/cache');` call comes **above** `$feed->init();`